# Payment gateway URL subdomain

Tags: ssl, payment-gateway

We're considering setting up a subdomain `gateway.domain.com` where that sub domain will process all of our payments to authorize.net from possibly multiple sections of our site, our internal and external systems alike.  I know it would need SSL and I'm guessing I should accept $_POST from a restricted list of URLs and extreme data validation.

I'm wondering what your thoughts are on this.  Are there any security risks that I'm not thinking of?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Putting it on a subdomain doesn't have any security issues associated with it in concept as where the payments are handled on your website really doesn't mean anything as far as payment processing goes. All the usual security issues still apply regardless of where you put it on your website.

There are also no real benefits to this either other than, perhaps, you only need to get an SSL certificate for that subdomain assuming you don't need it anywhere else on your website. But that's barely a benefit if one at all.

Comment: Authorize only accepts payments from a single domain or subdomain per account.  So by processing them all through 1 subdomain we gain the ability to process credit cards on multiple subdomains accross our site via 1 authorize account instead of multiple.

Comment: Are you sure about that? I am a certified Authnet developer and have done dozens of integrations for them I don't know of that requirement existing. Can you provide me to a link where it states that?